Go to the bottom on chat
I'd like to go to the bottom in the list builder, on the last message and auto scroll to the bottom. I would like the newer messages to the bottom like WhatsApp or other chat.
I'm tested a lot of solution without success. Please let me know how can I solve this issue.
Thanks you.
here the code :
 Future<ResponseGetDiscussionMessage> getDiscussionMessage(
    {required idDiscussion}) async {
  ResponseGetDiscussionMessage? responseGetDiscussionMessage;

  Map<String, dynamic> customBody = {
    "action": 28,
    "idDiscussion": idDiscussion,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": null
  };

  var res = await ApiCallPost().apiCall(customBody);

  return ResponseGetDiscussionMessage.fromJson(res);
}
(...)

final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureCreateDiscussion =
        createDiscussion(name: "", idUser: widget.varToPage);

    // Scroll to bottom after the first frame is rendered
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => scrollToBottom());
  }

  // Method to scroll to the bottom
  void scrollToBottom() {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    }
  }
(...)
 @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _textNotifier.dispose();
    _controllerEnvoieMessage.dispose();

    _scrollController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

SizedBox(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                FutureBuilder<ResponseCreateDiscussion>(
                                    future: futureCreateDiscussion,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                                      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                          ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                        return const Center(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                        return Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                                'Erreur : ${snapshot.error}'));
                                      } else {
                                        discussionDetail['idDiscussion'] =
                                            snapshot.data!.result.id;
                                        futureGetDiscussionMessage =
                                            getDiscussionMessage(
                                                idDiscussion: discussionDetail[
                                                    'idDiscussion']);

                                        return Container(
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                  child: FutureBuilder<
                                                          ResponseGetDiscussionMessage>(
                                                      future:
                                                          futureGetDiscussionMessage,
                                                      builder:
                                                          (BuildContext context,
                                                              snapshot) {
                                                        if (snapshot
                                                                .connectionState ==
                                                            ConnectionState
                                                                .waiting) {
                                                          return const Center(
                                                              child:
                                                                  CircularProgressIndicator());
                                                        } else if (snapshot
                                                            .hasError) {
                                                          return Center(
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                  'Erreur : ${snapshot.error}'));
                                                        } else {
                                                          return ListView
                                                              .builder(
                                                                  //  controller: _scrollController,
                                                                  controller:
                                                                      _scrollController,
                                                                  //  reverse: true,
                                                                  itemCount: snapshot
                                                                          .data
                                                                          ?.result
                                                                          .length ??
                                                                      0,
                                                                  scrollDirection:
                                                                      Axis
                                                                          .vertical,
                                                                  shrinkWrap:
                                                                      true,
                                                                  physics:
                                                                      const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                                                  itemBuilder:
                                                                      (BuildContext
                                                                              contex,
                                                                          int index) {
                                                                    String? lastUser = index ==
                                                                            0
                                                                        ? null
                                                                        : snapshot
                                                                            .data!
                                                                            .result[index -
                                                                                1]
                                                                            .firstname;

                                                                    bool isFirstMessageForUser = lastUser !=
                                                                        snapshot
                                                                            .data!
                                                                            .result[index]
                                                                            .firstname;

                                                                    return Align(
                                                                        alignment: snapshot.data!.result[index].isOwner ==
                                                                                false
                                                                            ? Alignment.topLeft
                                                                            : Alignment.topRight,
                                                                        child: Container(
                                                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                                                                            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                                                              maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                                                                            ),
                                                                            child: IntrinsicWidth(
                                                                                child: Card(
                                                                                    color: ColorsDiolos.vertClair,
                                                                                    elevation: 0,
                                                                                    child: Container(
                                                                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                                                                                        alignment: snapshot.data!.result[index].isOwner == false ? Alignment.topLeft : Alignment.topRight,
                                                                                        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                                                                                          Text("${snapshot.data!.result[index].date}"),
                                                                                          if (isFirstMessageForUser)
                                                                                            Row(
                                                                                              children: [
                                                                                                CircleAvatar(
                                                                                                  radius: 20,
                                                                                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage("$urlSite/file/user-profile/${snapshot.data!.result[index].image}"),
                                                                                                ),
                                                                                                Text(
                                                                                                  "${snapshot.data!.result[index].firstname}",
                                                                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                                                                    color: ColorsDiolos.violetClair,
                                                                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                                                  ),
                                                                                                ),
                                                                                              ],
                                                                                            ),
                                                                                          Align(
                                                                                              alignment: snapshot.data!.result[index].isOwner == false ? Alignment.topLeft : Alignment.topRight,
                                                                                              child: Text(
                                                                                                "${snapshot.data!.result[index].data!.text}",
                                                                                                style: TextStyle(color: ColorsDiolos.violetFonce, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: (snapshot.data!.result[index].data!.text!.length > 2) || (isEmoji("${snapshot.data!.result[index].data!.text}") == false) ? 17 : 60),
                                                                                              ))
                                                                                        ]))))));
                                                                  });
                                                        }
                                                      }))
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    }),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        

(...)

I would like to read the message with the last to the top and last to the bottom.

Use scrollToBottom when add new comment not atinitState

Solved. I put the controller on SingleChildScrollView() and not with ListView.builder
Thank you,

To implement auto-scrolling in a ListView like a chat application, where new messages appear at the bottom, here are a few steps that should help achieve the desired behavior.
Solution Steps
1.  Reverse the ListView so new messages appear at the bottom.
2.  Use a Scroll Controller to handle the auto-scrolling logic.
3.  Ensure auto-scrolling occurs after the widget frame is built, especially when new messages are added.

Complete Code Solution
Here’s an updated version of your code that includes these steps. It uses WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback to scroll after the UI frame is rendered, ensuring smooth scrolling to the bottom whenever a new message arrives.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String varToPage;

  ChatScreen({required this.varToPage});

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  late Future<void> futureCreateDiscussion;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureCreateDiscussion = createDiscussion(name: "", idUser: widget.varToPage);
    
    // Scroll to bottom after the first frame is rendered
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => scrollToBottom());
  }

  // Method to scroll to the bottom
  void scrollToBottom() {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Chat")),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: futureCreateDiscussion,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text("Error loading messages"));
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.result.length ?? 0,
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final message = snapshot.data!.result[index];
                final isOwner = message.isOwner;
                final alignment = isOwner ? Alignment.topRight : Alignment.topLeft;

                return Align(
                  alignment: alignment,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                    ),
                    child: Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(message.content),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> createDiscussion({required String name, required String idUser}) async {
    // Your async logic to create a discussion goes here.
  }
}

Explanation of Changes:
•   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback: By using this in initState, the scrolling happens after the widget tree has been built, ensuring the view starts at the bottom after initial loading.
•   Updated scrollToBottom Method: This method checks if _scrollController has clients before scrolling, avoiding errors when the list view isn’t ready.

With this setup, each time a new message is added, the ListView will scroll to the latest message at the bottom. This simulates the chat behavior you see in messaging apps like WhatsApp.

Same behavior. But I updated the code because I was forget a future. I need two future to return a discussion with two person.

Another behavior very strange. When I'm using this line, the list go to the bottom and after that It goes to the top. _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent + 300,
